# [FIFO]getline blocking when reading from a FIFO

Tags: fifo

I have two processes. One is a producer that writes data to a FIFO file opened in O_RDWR mode. The other process is a consumer . It opens the FIFO in "read mode" using a file pointer.

When producer writes data to FIFO , consumer is reading the data from the FIFO using getline. When producer stops writing data , getline returns -1 with "ferror". After 2-3 hours with producer not writing any data to the FIFO , the getline call blocks the consumer process.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us the code? Is there any memory leak issue?

Comment: There is no memory leak. 
Here is the code:
PRODUCER :
mkfifo(file_name.data(), 0666) 
...
open(file_name.data(),O_RDWR)
...
write(fifo->fd_, records[i].data(), records[i].size())
....

CONSUMER: 
fp = fopen( fifo_path.c_str(), "r"); line = NULL;
len = 0;
c_read = getline(&line, &len, fp);

Comment: I am also doing some signal handling. When a SIGTERM or SIGHUP occurs i handle it in a signal handler and return.